# What is the joint cumulative distribution function of two separate uniformly distributions ~[0,1]?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I was asked to find a joint distribution for two suppliers where each alone has a uniformly distributed demand~U[0,1], how do I do that?

In general is it possible to join in general any two non identical distributions?

Answer (score 1):

If the distributions for two suppliers are independent, then the joint distribution is simple. In general we need:
$$
f_{X,Y} = \iint_R f(x,y) dx dy = 1
$$

Here the region is the unit square, and $f_{X,Y}$ is the constant $1$ as:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 dx dy = 1
$$

So the density is:
$$
f_{X,Y} = \begin{cases}
1 &x,y \in [0,1]\\
0, &\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and the distribution is:
$$
F_{X,Y} = \begin{cases}
xy &x,y \in [0,1]\\
0, &\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$